# Assemble a Karaf container with my dependencies

Tags: maven, osgi, karaf

I was able to assemble a karaf container with standard and webconsole features in a new module:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
        <type>kar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <classifier>features</classifier>
        <type>xml</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.karaf.features.framework.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <bootFeatures>
                    <feature>standard</feature>
                    <feature>webconsole</feature>
                </bootFeatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: Karaf Webconsole]

[image: Target folder with Karaf assembled]

Now, I want to do some more, I want to add my other modules/code to this container to start it together and test my code, my REST calls and so on...

One of my modules is something like this:

```
<artifactId>config-testutils</artifactId>

<properties>
    <bundle.symbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</bundle.symbolicName>
    <bundle.namespace>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</bundle.namespace>
</properties>

<name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

How can I add those modules to see if they are working fine in this Karaf I'm assembling? There is a way besides putting manually on deploy folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a feature that contains your own bundles and add it in `<bootFeatures>`